# GWT i18n renders key rather than value

Tags: java, gwt, maven, internationalization

So I've read this dozens of times.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideStaticStringInternationalization

I've googled around and I'm not seeing anything related to diagnosing the problem I have.

I have a UiMessages interface that extends Messages. I spec my keys with methods like

```
@DefaultMessage("Open")
@Key("open")
String open();
```

In addition I add a static instance variable to the interface

```
public static final UiMessages INSTANCE = GWT.create(UiMessages.class);
```

so I can access the UiMessages like

```
UiMessages.INSTANCE.open();
```

I have a UiMessages_en.properties file in same package as UiMessages.java w/

```
open=Open
```

So in a widget I inject a field

```
@UiField Label status;
```

that was spec'd in a ui.xml like

```
<g:Label ui:field="status" />
```

Can someone please tell me why when I set

```
   status.setText(UiMessages.INSTANCE.open());
```

I get "open" rather than "Open"?

Oh yeah... I'm running GWT 2.4 hosted mode on Windows 7, Jdk 6, Maven 3, via gwt-maven-plugin 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly error on my part. Strings are immutable.